# Excel 2010 : Find seconds between two date time

Tags: excel, macros

I have a column `Cal Date time`, which contains the date and time of the call as shown below.

```
A       B                           C           D
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number  Call Date Time                          Duration(in Sec)
123     2010-01-10-01.07.24.465000                  ?
123     2010-01-10-01.07.24.783000      
234     2010-01-12-01.09.45.186000                  ?
234     2010-01-12-01.11.40.186000      
896     2010-01-13-10.10.35.186000                  ?
896     2010-01-13-11.10.45.186000
```

**Note**: I want to calculate the duration of call in the column `D` of the each number in the seconds.

Comment: what format is the cell? text?

Comment: @BryanDavies, Yes its a text format.

Comment: I assume that is a 

yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss.xxxx format? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Alright, normally people around here make you have a crack yourself. But I'm about to set a bounty question, so I need the rep. Check below

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you need to format a cell as custom like this: [image]

Then use this formula in it

```
=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(B3,10),2)&"/"&RIGHT(LEFT(B3,7),2)&"/"&LEFT(B3,4))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(B3,13),2)&":"&RIGHT(LEFT(B3,16),2)&":"&RIGHT(B3,9))
```

Where B3 is your text data.

you can do a simple subtract after that

Comment: So how long is a call from 2010-01-10-23.59.59.465000 to 2010-01-11-00.00.10.333000?

Comment: ah yes... alright, lets make this a little bit better then. give a couple mins