# Calculate seconds from two datetime

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

I want to write a excel macro, which should calculate the seconds from the two datetime.

I have the following format of datetime in a single column.

```
DateColumn
--------------------------
2010-01-10-01.07.24.465000
2010-01-10-01.08.25.575000
```

How to calculate the how many seconds difference in the above datetime using macro?

Comment: agree with @HynekBernard. always use built-in formula first. unless speed is not a concern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel 2010 : Find seconds between two date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181833/excel-2010-find-seconds-between-two-date-time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `Datediff()` Function.

[Here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php) you got some documentation. You can choose seconds in the first parameter

Anyways it is better and easier to do this by formula.

Answer (score 0):

The `DateDiff` function will give you exactly what you need:

```
timestamp1 = "2010-01-10-01.07.24.465000"
timestamp2 = "2010-01-10-01.08.25.575000"

myDiff = DateDiff("s", timestamp1, timestamp2) ' use "s" to get difference in seconds
```

You can find out about the various interval types (seconds in the example above) by looking [here](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwixqvO85tnNAhVTrRQKHXYwAzUQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.techonthenet.com%2Fexcel%2Fformulas%2Fdatediff.php&usg=AFQjCNEfIriDjHNNqBIH7ftN9gM7CIWt7w&bvm=bv.126130881,d.d24) for more information

Answer (score 0):

I already answered this....

[Excel 2010 : Find seconds between two date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181833/excel-2010-find-seconds-between-two-date-time)
    =DATEVALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(B3,10),2)&"/"&RIGHT(LEFT(B3,7),2)&"/"&LEFT(B3,4))+TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(B3,13),2)&":"&RIGHT(LEFT(B3,16),2)&":"&RIGHT(B3,9))

pretty bad form to repost... and not give any rep on the first one.

Comment: Bryan you can flag to close as a duplicate. Agree it is a bit annoying - I just spent 5 minutes fiddling with the daft format ;)

Comment: I just want the rep as I need to ask a bounty question soon :(

Comment: If you want rep then the Excel VBA tag is not your best choice ;-)

Comment: haha, its what I am best at and can answer.

And I like helping people